# Elasticsearch delete debug syslog messages older than x days and with a certain term

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to get rid of debug syslog Messages after a certain amount of time.
The query is running without Errors but isn´t deleting any data:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/logstash-syslog-vmware/_delete_by_query?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : { 
            "must" : {
                "match" : {
                    "syslog_severity" : "debug" }
                }, 
            "filter" : { 
                "range" : {
                    "@timestamp" : { 
                        "gt" : "2017-10-13T09:00:00", 
                        "lt" : "2017-10-13T11:30:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: Elasticsearch Version is 5.6.2

Comment: If you use that query with the `_search` endpoint, how many results do you get?

Comment: nothing...
when changing "logstash-syslog-vmware" to "logstash-syslog-vmware-*" it´s working

thanks for the hint.

Comment: There you go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer that has been solved as per comment (using a wildcard) but let me say something.

If you intend to purge everyday the debug level old documents then I'd recommend using different indices:

One for the `trace`, `debug` levels and another for the others.
Then when you need to purge old data, just drop the index like `DELETE logstash-syslog-vmware-debug-2017-10-13`.

It will be much more efficient.

If it was only a one go operation, then feel free to ignore me :)